# CSS - Image scaling / avoiding stretch and squash

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

I have a section in a website that consists of eight images arranged in two rows of four. Each image shell - `grid-item` - will contain a different image with different original dimensions. I need, somehow, to avoid any kind of scaling of the images when the screen size is being reduced. I've tried numerous ways to avoid this but still cannot find the solution. I'm pretty sure the dimensions are key - how can I change this?

The last solution I tried was to follow this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLc2Le0k/120/) from a previous Q&A on here but this only works if I alter the height ruling (which, ultimately then distorts the image arrangement).

I've also looked at masonry but, again, the height rules don't work.

Here's the code as I have it at the moment (for the benefit of this question I've used the same image file for each `grid-item` ) -

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
  margin: 3em;
}

 #block1 {
  grid-row: span 4;
  
}



.grid-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  
}

.grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}


/* RWD  */

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {


      .grid-container {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    }

         #block1 {
          grid-row: span 2;
  
            }

    
}




 

@media only screen and (min-width: 560px) and (max-width: 960px)  {
   
          .grid-container {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

        #block1 {
          grid-row: span 2;
  
            }

}




@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1300px) {

    .grid-container {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }

        #block1 {
          grid-row: span 3;
  
          }
  

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
    .grid-container {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }

            #block1 {
              grid-row: span 4;
  
        }
   
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item" id="block1">
              <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507199659/graphic_design_rbakaf.jpg">       
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="block1">
              <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507199659/graphic_design_rbakaf.jpg">       
      </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="block1">
              <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507199659/graphic_design_rbakaf.jpg">       
      </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="block1">
              <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507199659/graphic_design_rbakaf.jpg">       
      </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="block1">
              <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507199659/graphic_design_rbakaf.jpg">       
      </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="block1">
              <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507199659/graphic_design_rbakaf.jpg">       
      </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="block1">
              <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507199659/graphic_design_rbakaf.jpg">       
      </div>
    <div class="grid-item" id="block1">
              <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1507199659/graphic_design_rbakaf.jpg">       
      </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT UPDATE -**

If I use different images with `height: auto` then this is what happens (looks a lot like masonry)

[image: Image scaling with height set at auto]

Answer (score 0):

`flexbox` solves your problem

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgL6z2be/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. What does the * represent in the styling, is that for the body?

Comment: It is actually a universal selector. Look at this article: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/


Make sure you mark the answer as correct too. :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It still distorts the height of the image - I need them all to be at a set height as per my example. If you use different images then their heights are all different. I've just added an image to illustrate what  I mean.